# USB HID Devices

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I'm looking for one of either 2 things

1 - A working example of code using Florian's library from: http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/

This seems to be one of the better (only???) C#/HID libraries but the author has gone MIA and I can't seem to get a code example to work. The code I have is:

```
{
    USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface usb = new USBInterface(myvid,mypid);
    if (usb.Connect())
        MessageBox.Show(”connection!”);
    else
        MessageBox.Show(”FAIL”);

    usb.enableUsbBufferEvent(new System.EventHandler(myEventCacher));
    usb.startRead();
}

private void myEventCacher(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string content = e.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(content);
}
```

The connection part works but the event proc is never fired. So I'd like to know if anyone has a working example of this library code with the event handler firing.

2 - If there is a better library for handling C#/HID interaction I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library you mention is now hosted on google see http://code.google.com/p/csharp-usb-hid-driver/

Perhaps these are helpful too:

- https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary
- http://www.usbhidnetclass.com/ (commercial) (usbhidnetclass.org previously)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx
- http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HIDAche.aspx?q=C%23+and+USB+HID+Devices
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/530836/Csharp-USB-HID-Interface

Comment: Yes, I'd found the Google link. But that place is just a placeholder - all links refer back to Florian's web site which is what I posted up top.

Comment: check the rest of the links out - some are really promisiong as far as I can tell...

Comment: An interesting note.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx and http://www.usbhidnetclass.org/ use the exact same code.  I'm not sure who copied who, but the code is essentially identical even down to some of the variable names.  The objects even custom exceptions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

In Florian's project, take a look at TestFixture.cs. It's his unit test, but in it you'll see an example use of his code. You'll need to send a command to your device before you'll receive a message back.

I would recommend http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx from the links above. I also had trouble with Florian's driver. The Code Project driver worked for me. If you use the Code Project driver there are small modifications which you need to make if you are using a Windows 7 x64 project. They are hidden in the page's comment section.

Comment: "the page's comment section"? Webpages? I couldn't find any

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C?msg=3616281#xx3616281xx  This link contains the message with code fixes for x64.