# How to write driver for HID device in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, driver

I am new in writing diver for HID device. So please tell me how can i start to writing driver for HID device using c# windows application.

Comment: This is either too broad (you can't explain whether and how to write drivers in .NET in a few sentences), unclear what you're asking (what _exactly_ do you need help with?) or the same as [C# and USB HID Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164055/c-sharp-and-usb-hid-devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a driver in .NET is more or less impossible (more importantly, getting .NET anywhere near the kernel is a bad idea; user mode drivers are an option (although only a recent one on Windows) - but it's still somewhat tricky). However, to use a HID device, you don't have to write a driver, as long as you only want to use the HID out of your application and not eg. Explorer.

A good start might be something like https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary.