# C# ReadFile() Error Code 1008

Tags: c#, windows, error-code

I am using an HID Library, when I call device.ReadInput() (Which really just calls the Windows ReadFile() function), the function fails and I get a 1008 error code.

1008 means ERROR_NO_TOKEN. (An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist).

Does anyone know what this means, especially in reference to the Windows ReadFile() function?

```
Debug.WriteLine("About to read...");
bool read = device.ReadInput();
byte[] dataBuf = device.Inputs.DataBuf;
byte[] retData;

if (!read) {
    int x = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Debug.WriteLine("Error code: " + x);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to open a pipe created by another process? perhaps a background service? It will be a permissions thing.....you will need to create the pipe with a security descriptor so that your client can get access I believe - there are secure and non-secure ways to do that. Or perhaps you are using Impersonation and did that in one thread but you are trying to use that handle in other thread which isn't impersonating...or even used OpenThreadtoken? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813414/how-to-create-an-anonymous-pipe-that-gives-access-to-everyone

Comment: The library I am using is closed source, so unfortunately I cannot see what they are doing the device.ReadInput() is a library call so I am not sure what they are doing in there.

But, I am calling the device.ReadInput() from within a separate thread from the main thread, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Is it a keyboard device? - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C?msg=3225925#xx3225925xx

Comment: @ColinSmith No, it is a custom HID board.

Comment: Is your code running as an NT Service, or within an application with an interactive logged on user?

Comment: @ColinSmith My code is a C# Windows Form Program. A user logs in clicks the .exe and can interact with a form that sends commands via HID to the board.

Comment: was it any one of these libraries mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164055/c-sharp-and-usb-hid-devices

Comment: @ColinSmith No, it is a cypress library because my board uses a cypress chip. CyUSB.dll is the name of the dll. Also, I should note that I have had it worked randomly in the past, but now it does not want to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141578/discussion-between-dylan-holmes-and-colin-smith).

Comment: Are you certain that the call to ReadFile is being made with the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError field set, and that it is the last such call made before you call GetLastWin32ErrorCode?

Comment: ... Sysinternals Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might be useful, to double-check that the error code you're getting really is coming from the call to ReadFile.  (Though it certainly could be, if there's impersonation taking place.)