# Reading data with Custom HID

Tags: c#, hid

I want to read from my *STM32* card using **custom HID** over USB to get the *C#* data transfer rate close to ideal.

I don't have a problem with the codes I wrote on the STM32 side. Data comes in at a very good speed.

However, I have a problem with coding on the C# side. As far as I understand there are no Custom HID functions in internal libraries in C#. I looked at libraries from Nuget and Github. The libraries I'm looking at are either missing or I haven't been able to. Has anyone worked on this before? I'm open to your ideas. Thanks already for your help.

Libraries i tried

- LibUsbDotNet
- Device.Net/HID.Net/Usb.Net

Reading data with Custom HID in C#

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7164055/982149 ... seems related.

Comment: We get it c#… don’t have to mention it once in tags, twice in title and four times in body